# No provider for TranslateService

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I add ng-translate on my project depending the documentation but still have a error

```
    //import
        import {TranslateLoader, TranslateModule, TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';

    //also provides 
        providers: [
            {provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-US'},
            BaseRequestOptions,
            { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptor, multi: true },
          { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CommonInterceptor, multi: true },
          NGXLogger,
          TranslateService
        ],

//and 
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
```

Comment: That's a module. Now provide a *service*.

Comment: please provide your code for TranslateLoader

Comment: are you using AOT?

Comment: yes @GouravGarg i use AOT.

Comment: @HienNguyen i just edited the post

Comment: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#configuration  check AOT specific
// AoT requires an exported function for factories

Comment: It was working fine until i upgrade my project to angular 7

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have added the snippet in imports block of `app.module.ts`
for example:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,

    // configure the imports
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
});
```